# Left aligned equations

Tags: alignat, alignment

In my document, I have a block of 3 equations that need to be aligned on the `=` sign. This is the code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
      &\text{xxxxxxx1}       &&= 1/y  \\
      &\text{x2} &&=y      \\
      &\text{x3}       &&=y^2+x2
   \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

However, I'd also like this block of equations to be left-aligned. Instead, with that code, it is centered on the page.

In a related post, someone suggested to use `fleqn` as a document class. Nevertheless, I cannot use that, because some of the equations in my document have to be centered, not all of them have to be left-aligned.

Comment: You want just these three to be aligned on the left margin, but still numbered at the right margin?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All equations in my document are numbered at the right margin, but I do not want all of them to be aligned at the left margin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is not very clear to me what you like to obtain, so below are two options which cross my mind:

- in the first is used `flalign` math environment from the `amsmath` package
- in second the `gather` environment (also from `amsmat`) is enclosed in  `fleqn` environment proviedad by he package `nccmath`

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
     \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{nccmath}

    %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------%

     \begin{document}

        \begin{flalign}
    \text{xxxxxxx1}  &= 1/y     &\\
    \text{x2}        &= y       &\\
    \text{x3}        &= y^2+x2  &
       \end{flalign}

    or

        \begin{fleqn}
        \begin{gather}
    \text{xxxxxxx1}  = 1/y      \\
    \text{x2}        = y        \\
    \text{x3}        = y^2+x2
        \end{gather}
       \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

**edit:** 
from your comments follows that you like to have something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{xxxxxxx1} &&= 1/y      \\
&\text{x2}       &&= y        \\
&\text{x3}       &&= y^2+x2
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first option is the most similar to what I'd like to obtain; however I'd like to also have x2 and x3 aligned at the left margin

Comment: this means, that you like to big space between left side of equations and `=` sign?

Comment: Exactly. I cannot manage to do that with `alignat`, nor with `flalign`

Comment: I took the liberty of simplifying the last code also to get the spacing right. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much. i now is better!

Comment: @Zarko, thank you so much, that is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

A solution not really completely automated, but you can do your job till find a completed automated method:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mylongbox}
\newsavebox{\mybox} 
\newcommand{\longer}[1]{\savebox\mylongbox{\hbox{$#1$}}}
\newcommand{\forceLeft}[1]{\savebox{\mybox{$#1$}}\usebox{\mybox}\hspace{\dimexpr\wd\mylongbox-\wd\mybox}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

%Store the longer item
\longer{\text{xxxxxxx1}}
        \begin{flalign}
    \text{xxxxxxx1}  &= 1/y     &\\
%Use \forceleft command for the others
    \forceLeft{\text{x2}}      &= y       &\\
    \forceLeft{\frac{1}{3}\cdot x_2}        &= y^2+x2  &
       \end{flalign}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome Mary.